# Python: Optimize deletion of elements not aligned in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, optimization, numpy

I'm working with very big matrices using **numpy 1.6.2** and **python 2.7**.
Given an `N x M` matrix `A` and a map `B` where I can find, for each row, the index of the element to delete.
Here is an example:

```
A =

   26   55   29   30
   31   65   34   35
   36   75   39   40
   41   85   44   45
   46   95   49   50

B =

     2
     0
     1
     3
     2
```

The result will be:

```
A =

   26   55   30
   65   34   35
   36   39   40
   41   85   44
   46   95   50
```

Actually to obtain this I create a loop like this:

```
for i in xrange(size(B)):
  A[i,:] = concatenate(A[i,0:B[i]],A[i,B[i]+1:])
```

But it is really slow.
Is there a faster way to delete the elements I need?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a mask for `A` like this:

```
>>> mask = np.arange(4) != np.vstack(B)
>>> mask
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

And then use this to filter out the unwanted (`False`) values from `A`, reshape, and then rebind to the variable name `A`:

```
>>> A = A[mask].reshape(5, 3)
>>> A
array([[26, 55, 30],
       [65, 34, 35],
       [36, 39, 40],
       [41, 85, 44],
       [46, 95, 50]])
```

This should be quicker than using `concatenate` because it avoids copying arrays for each iteration of the Python `for` loop.